# Exiting a while loop in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float celsius, fahrenheit;
    while(true) {

    printf("Please input a temperature in Celsius (type 'stop' to stop): " );
    scanf("%f", &celsius);

    fahrenheit = (1.8 * celsius) + 32;
    printf("Temperature in Fahrenheit: %f ", fahrenheit);
    }

    return(0);

}
```

I am attempting to write a program in C that converts celsius to fahrenheit.  I want the program to continue looping, until the user enters 'stop.'  What is the best way to exit to while loops in C?

Comment: @JiangYD That's not going to work because Celsius is a float.

Comment: my mistake. change it to a string, and use atof to convert to double after comparing with "stop" failed.

Comment: `if(1!=scanf("%f", &celsius)) break;` this isn't rigorous. but easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Since `stop` won't be converted to a floating point number, you should test the return value from `scanf()`, thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float celsius, fahrenheit;
    while (1)
   {
        printf("Please input a temperature in Celsius (type 'stop' to stop): ");
        if (scanf("%f", &celsius) != 1)
            break;

        fahrenheit = (1.8 * celsius) + 32;
        printf("Temperature in Fahrenheit: %f\n", fahrenheit);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

The `break` statement actually breaks the loop.  Note that this will stop if you type 'abracadabra', or anything else that is not a floating point value.  Terminate non-prompt outputs with a newline.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do you know how I would go about reducing the number of trailing numbers for the output?  For example, when the program prints out the temp in fahrenheit, it prints out something like 35.599998.  I cannot figure out how to round this to two decimal places.

Comment: For that, specify `%.2f` which should round to 2 d.p.

Comment: Incidentally, I like the symmetric formulae: C = (F + 40) * 5 / 9 - 40; F = (C + 40) * 9 / 5 - 40;

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a while loop that breaks if you input "stop" is to read the input as a string first, then check if the input is equal to "stop", if not then convert it to a floating point variable. I have done some changes to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE     0x20

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char buffer [ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    char *exitword = "stop";
    float celsius, fahrenheit;

    while ( 0x01 )
    {
            memset ( buffer, 0x00, BUFFER_SIZE );

            printf("Please input a temperature in Celsius (type '%s' to stop): ", exitword );

            if ( fgets ( buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 0x01, stdin ) == NULL )
            {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "Unable to read user input!\n" );
                    fprintf ( stderr, "Please try again\n" );
                    continue;
            }

            if ( strncmp ( buffer, exitword, strlen ( exitword )) == 0x00 )
            {
                    printf ( "Good bye!\n" );
                    break;
            }

            if (( celsius = strtof ( buffer, NULL )) == 0 )
            {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "Unable to convert user input to floating point number\n" );
                    fprintf ( stderr, "Please try again\n" );
                    continue;
            }

            fahrenheit = (1.8 * celsius) + 32;
            printf("Temperature in Fahrenheit: %f\n", fahrenheit);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Various points: (1) `memset()` is unnecessary; (2) `0x01` is a long-winded way of writing `1` and `0x00` is usually written `0`; (3) a buffer size of 32 (or 0x20) is quite short — people can write longer lines than that and your code will read the residue as a new line of input, even though the user didn't type anything more; (4) `strncmp()` looks for a prefix, so `stopping` will be recognized as equal to `stop`; (5) freezing point in Celsius is 0 ºC, so insisting that `0` is erroneous is a bit unfortunate. However, you report errors to `stderr`, and you do check for the most important errors.